# Conda in mac gets corrupted after mac system cache deletion

Tags: python, macos, anaconda, conda, environment

I accidentally removed all files from "~/Library/Caches" on my mac. After that my conda environments are not working. For example: my previously working code is showing "import error" for numpy, matplotlib, etc. After reinstalling these libraries using either "conda" or "pip" command they are still missing and can not find in conda list. Furthermore, **conda update conda** or **create env** commands are hanged on **"Solving environment"**.

Is there any way to solve this problem without reinstalling the anaconda?

Comment: Try reinstalling conda

Comment: This seems odd. Have you installed Anaconda/Miniconda for all users (not typical)?

Comment: Reinstalling conda solved the issue. @droptop

Comment: No, I just installed for one user @merv